# Can I travel to New Zealand with a valid visa on an old/expired passport?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, passport-renewals

I recently renewed my passport (Brazil). I also have an expired passport, which has my New Zealand visa (permanent resident). I am planning to visit New Zealand.

Since my valid New Zealand visa is in my old/expired passport, do I need to renew/transfer my New Zealand visa or can I simply travel with valid visa in old passport?

Comment: I don't know what the case is for new zealand but in some countries "permanent residence" can be less permanent than the name implies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you have renewed your passport (because it has expired, was
>   lost/stolen or your name has changed), you need to transfer your valid
>   visa into your new passport before you use it to travel. This applies
>   regardless of whether you have a physical visa label or an e-visa or
>   other label-less visa.

Source: https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/transferring-my-visa-to-a-new-passport

Follow the link for information on the process for transferring a visa into a new passport.